# Example for Model-dependant state ember concept using cache

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Below is my route,

this.route('posts',{path: 'posts/:PostId/:PageIndex/:PageSize'});

For the postId=1 user is creating some filter stuff and navigates to postId=2 and comes back to postId=1 then user should be able to view created filters.
Typically, I would like to persist some controller sticky properties to each route user visits. how to do that ?.

Comment: Why not use query params?

Comment: @Lux User creating filter is complex model, i don't want it to be in URL. and also i would like to persists unsaved filter specific to each postId using cache.

Comment: Controllers are singleton. You can create a cache in corresponding controller and relate to post model. Also there are another ways too